# "expected a '>'" in class template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm writing a class that I would like to only be used with types that the std::is_arithmetic template applies to. My code is the following:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename A, typename B>
class Stream {};

template <typename T>
class Stream <typename T,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type * = nullptr> {
    //...
};
```

The compiler is telling me that the '=' is a syntax error because it was expecting a '>', which doesn't make much sense. I feel like I haven't quite got the grasp of partial template specialization just yet, what am I missing?

Comment: While errors involving templates often can be large and seem weird, please include the full and complete output anyway. And also try to create a proper [mcve] that replicates the error, as sometimes the error could be in how you use the template.

Comment: Try removing `typename` after `class Stream <`; only `class Stream <T, `

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I edited the post to contain code that can be compiled to get the error I get. The error literally just being `error C2059: syntax error: '='`

Comment: @max66 I tried to no avail, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a specialization, the template parameter list that follows the class name must only contain types and values.

You can't put default arguments in there, they belong in the primary template.
And you don't need `typename` there (unless you have a dependent type, e.g. `typename std::enable_if<...T...>`).

Here's a working version of your code:

```
template<typename A, typename = void>
class Stream {};

template <typename T>
class Stream<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>>
{};
```

---

Note that it's possible to circumvent the check by passing a non-`void` type to second parameter. You should probably add a `static_assert(std::is_void_v<T>);` to the primary template to prevent an accidental misuse.

Comment: That definitely solved it, thank you! Now every time I want to define a function outside of the Stream class that I declared it in though, it seems like I have to type out the entire template parameter list, which seems unnecessary and also makes the code less readable. I have a function called `Stream::next()` for example, and defining it consists of this: `template<typename T>
inline std::shared_ptr<T> Stream<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>>::next() { ... }`, which is exactly what I wanted to avoid by using default template arguments. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: @Bobobot You can move all your functions to a separate template (a regular class template with a single parameter), and make the specialization of `Stream` inherit from it. Or, if you define your functions in the same file as the class, you can move them to the class body (if your IDE can fold functions, you barely gain any readability by defining them outside).